# Flutter: Class 'String' has no instance method 'call'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
final leaseMap = lease as Map;
          await firebaseProfile.createLease(context, lease).then((newLease) {
            leaseMap['documentID'] = newLease.id(); // despite this returns an string it fails
          });
```

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no
> instance method 'call'. E/flutter ( 9361): Receiver:
> "ID" E/flutter ( 9361): Tried calling: call()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`leaseMap['documentID'] = newLease.id;`

without ()

Comment: omg... I feel so stupid. I just duplicated the above line where I was getting data() and didn't realise :D